# How to include space and new line in regular expression?

Tags: node.js, regex, c#-4.0

I have an HTML file which contains the below code snippet.

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">
<div class="countBox success" id="success">
<h2>467</h2>
                    Passed Tests
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have a regular expression **(.*)</h2>\r\nPassed** to get the value 467. It is worked till yesterday. But, it is not working now. I have tried by replacing single slash by double slash to new line and row. Used "\s+" to cover whitespace. All failed in error. Could anyone please guide me on how to get the value as 467 by using regular expression for the above code snippet?

Comment: Regular expression format should be like <h2>(.*)<\/h2>\r\nPassed. Output should be 467

Comment: I don't see how it worked yesterday or any other day, unless the beginning of line looked like `467</h2>\nPassed`. What you're looking for is to replace the `\r\n` with `\s*` and the `(.*)` with `(\d+)`.

Comment: @sln, Please see my above comment. Am using this regular expression.  <h2>(.*)<\/h2>\r\nPassed. This is not working now.

Comment: Well, you want a delimited version with some whitespace consideration (and a quantifier mod) [/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>\s*Passed/](https://regex101.com/r/GqTmDD/1) give it a try..

Comment: Try this `(?is)<h2>(.*?)</h2>.*?Passed`

Comment: @sln It's not working

Comment: @Tim.Tang It's not working

Comment: Why @Karthi it sure is working, it's just a click away **[/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>\s*Passed/](https://regex101.com/r/GqTmDD/1)**

Comment: @sln it's working with <h2>(.*?)<\/h2>\\s*Passed

Comment: @Karthi - Nope, it's not working with **[<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>\\s*Passed](https://regex101.com/r/GqTmDD/2)** try again.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to catch `<h2>(\d+)</h2>` to ensure only a `h2` header with a number inside.  By the way, `\r\n` is only one convention (in windows) to represent end of line, but in unix it is only `\n` so to be more platform independent, you can do `\r?\n` (marking the `\r` as optional)  and you have to get on the whitespace in front of `Passed.`, so a good (but not probably the best) regexp would be:

```
<h2>(\d+)<\/h2>\r?\n\s*Passed
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LpAafk/1).